# Determining Practical Numbers

Tags: python

So I am given a fraction and must determine if the denominator is a practical number. Description of a practical number: [What is a practical number?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_number)

I already have a function that returns all the factors of the number:

```
def factorFinder(x):
    #Pre: Valid Integer for students
    #Post: Returns list of factors for that number
    #Takes the number of students as argument and returns all factors for that number
    lst = []
    for i in range(1, x+1):
        if x % i == 0:
            lst.append(i)
    return(lst)
```

and a function that given a list of factors as arguments returns a list of sums of all its sublists:

```
import itertools
def sumsOfSublists(lst):
    # Pre: a non-empty list
    # Post: returns a list of sums of all possible list sublists of length >= 2
    # given a list, returns a sorted list containing sums of
    # all combinations of sublists of length 2..list_length
    sumList = []
    for i in range(2, len(lst)+1):
       zlist = list(itertools.combinations(lst,i))
       for el in zlist:
           sumList.append(sum(el))
    return sorted(sumList)
```

I don't know how to go about testing if the number is practical or not. I don't really understand the concept of a "practical number" even after reading about it on multiple websites. So I guess really, this is more of a math question if anything.

Also given two number I need to print out the egyptian fractions for them. (i.e) given 7/8 should print the following: (1/2)+(1/4)+(1/8). All numerators must be 1.

Comment: why do you force conversion to `list` for `zlist` ? this is really sub-optimal. Iterators are there to avoid that.

Comment: you should [edit] your question to include the definition of a practical number in the question. Links may rot with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reformulate your wiki-article and hope that it is helpful to you - because as AChampion has said - you have already done all the heavy lifting ;)

n is is a practical number if:

- let **l** = [1, 2, ... n-1] // all number smaller than n
- let **divs** = [i for i in range(1,n) if n%i==0] // all divisors of n (I associate a factor is prime cause of the term factorization of a number, so probably you should change factor to divisor in your question)
- Now you have to write all numbers of **l** as sum of numbers from **divs**, where you can use all numbers of **divs** one or zero times

for example n = 12 is a practical number because:

- l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
- divs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
- l[0] = divs[0], l[1] = divs[1], ... , l[10] = divs[0]+divs[3]+divs[4]=1+4+6=11 // l[1] = divs[0]+divs[0] is not allowed because you may use each number of divs only once

In opposite n = 3 is not a practical number because:

- l = [1, 2]
- divs = [1]
- l[0] = divs[0], l[1] = mööööp

Here is also a straightforward implementation of my explanation (but you can also keep the nice work you have already done!):

```
from itertools import combinations

def isPracticalNumber(n):
    l = [i for i in range(1, n)]
    divs = [i for i in range(1, n) if n % i == 0]
    possibleSums = set()
    for i in range(1, len(divs)+1):
        combinationsOfLengthI = combinations(divs, i)
        for combi in combinationsOfLengthI:
            possibleSums.add(sum(combi))

    return all([i in possibleSums for i in l])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(isPracticalNumber(12)) # True
    print(isPracticalNumber(3)) # False

    practicalNumbers = [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 18, 20, 24, 28, 30, 32, 36, 40, 42, 48, 54, 56, 60, 64, 66, 72, 78, 80, 84, 88, 90, 96, 100, 104, 108, 112, 120, 126, 128, 132, 140, 144, 150]
    calculatedPracticalNumbers = [i for i in range(1, 151) if isPracticalNumber(i)]
    print(len(calculatedPracticalNumbers) == len(practicalNumbers) and all([i in practicalNumbers for i in calculatedPracticalNumbers]))
```

Comment: Giving the number 8 returns false, 8 is a practical number?

Comment: Sorry, silly mistake. corrected "for i in range(1, len(divs)+1)". Not enough tests and to quick coding - shame on me^^

Comment: Just tested with the first examples from Wiki. This should be enough :)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using the "combinations" from itertools?

Comment: you could of course implement combinations yourself - for example (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations). I am quite sure that you could also do it with dynamic programming technique instead - would be more efficient but also more complex. If you want that for efficiency, I suggest a new question would be appropriate

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've done all the heavy lifting you just need a check:

```
def is_practical(n):
    s = set(sumsOfSublists(factorFinder(n)))
    return all(i in s for i in range(1, n))
```

Is there any reason you are sorting the sums into a `list`? `set`s are much quicker to look up. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: We have to use lists.