# Egyptian fraction using Fibonacci's Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, fibonacci, fractions

I have this problem in which we are trying to find an Egyptian fraction using Fibonacci's algorithm. For the numerator, it is always must be equal to one. Then, we have to determine whether the bottom is a practical number.

We have 2 inputs from the user in which they give us a number (that must be positive)

I have already found a way to determine whether or not the bottom number of the rational number is a practical number..(a great similiar example : [Practical Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854400/determining-practical-numbers)) but I am lost on how to convert it to an Egyptian fraction.

In the instructions, it states that we should find the biggest fraction based off of our fractors list. For example: if the rational number is 5/8, the factors of 8 are [1,2,4]. The largest fraction that could be subtracted from this is 1/2.

I don't even know where to start with this conversion. I just know that if the second number from the user input is a practical number, I must calculate the equivalent egyptian fraction..

The output should run similiarly to this:

```
Num1 : 7
Num 2: 8
Denomiator factors: [1,2,4,8]
Num 2 is a practical number.
Fraction can be represented by:
1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8
```

Any starting help would be appreciated. I truly understand the concept and what it's asking - I am just stuck on where to start. Example codes would be a great help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You've come very close to stating the entire algorithm in your description.

Answer (score 0):

Okay ... I'm going to echo what you've just told us, using the example 7/8.

1. Start with the two parts of the fraction: numer=7, denom=8
2. Determine that **denom** is a practical number; this includes returning its factors, [1, 2, 4, 8].
3. Sort the factors in order; if you're guaranteed that the fraction is always less than 1, you can discard the **1** factor.
4. Iterate through the list, one factor at a time, building the terms of your Egyptian fraction.

pseudo-code:

```
for factor in factor_list:
    weight = denom/factor
    while weight < numer:
        # Add the fraction 1/factor to the solution;
        # reduce numer by weight (subtracting that fraction)
# When you exit these loops,
#   numer should be 0, and
#     you should have accumulated all of
#     the "1/factor" fractions in your solution.
```